# Unable to install Mocha Web3 and Ganache-cli

Tags: web3js, ganache, mocha

I have been trying to install mocha,Web3 and ganache all through one command but I am facing an issue while installing can someone help me in sorting our this error. Quick response will be appreciated .

```
npm install --save mocha ganache-cli web3@1.0.0-beta.26
```

Error 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gqn6.png

Comment: you need to install python in your machine

Answer (score 0):

No need to install python. It basically happened due to the fact that you can't install it globally.
 so use `sudo npm install --save mocha ganache-cli web3@1.0.0-beta.26`